# Twitter bootstrap clashing with my stylesheet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and the dropdownmenu does not display in blue background.
When I remove my site stylesheet dropdownmenu displays in blue.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container">
                                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                                    <ul class="nav">
                                        <li><a href="/Users/Share.aspx">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/Users/Friends.aspx">Friends</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reviews<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/Users/MovieReview.aspx">Movies</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Users/BookReview.aspx">Books</a></li>
                                                <%--<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>--%>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Share<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Share.aspx">Share</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Groups.aspx">Groups</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Personal<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Wall.aspx">Wall</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Messages.aspx">Messages</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Chatroom.aspx">Chat Room</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="/Users/ViewSong.aspx">Songs</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tech Ed<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/Users/Questions.aspx">Questions</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Users/AskQuestion.aspx">Ask Question</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="/Users/GroupNew.aspx">Groups</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                                
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="/Users/UpdateProfile.aspx">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server"></asp:Label></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a id="loginAnchor" href="LoginNew.aspx" runat="server" visible="false">Login</a></li>                                                
                                                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbAdminPanel" Text="Admin Panel" OnClick="lbAdminPanel_Click" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                                                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogout" Text="Log Out" OnClick="lbLogout_Click" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search" id="appendedInputButton" onclick="ClearSearchTextBox(this);" value="Search friends,movies,books,groups..." style="width: 160px; margin-top:5px;" />
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /navbar-inner -->
                    </div>
```

I don't understand why the two stylesheets are conflicting. How do I use the dropdownmenu properly?

Comment: Does your css contains a class name with "dropdown-menu" ?

Comment: No it does not contain

Comment: Can you share a link from jsfiddle?

Comment: @sly_Chandan We'd rather you post more of your relevant code on here or on jsFiddle, as other sites have the probability of being changed or dying in the future, which would hold no more benefit to future visitors of Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you could please visit my site www.friendisc.com then you can see that the dropdown menu isn't displaying in blue background.Instead its in gray background

Comment: You can always override it `!important;`

Comment: Its Resolved. I found which element it was colliding with and removed that element